# how to post data like this in flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm confuse to send data to server using this format.

[image: img]

anyone can help me please....

here is my code for post using Dio, but still not work :

```
Future<void> ajukanPengajuan() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    FormData formdata = FormData();
   

    formdata = FormData.fromMap({
       "id_petugas": Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .id_tersimpan
          .toString(),
      "penanggung_jawab": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .penanggung_jawab,
      "institusi":
          Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).institusi,
      "alamat": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).alamat,
      "lat": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).lat,
      "long": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).long,
      "sifat_pengajuan": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .sifat_pengajuan_dipilih,
      "alasan": Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).alasan,
      "apd_pengajuan": {
        "id_apd":
            Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).id_apdlist,
        "jumlah":
            Provider.of<PengajuanProvider>(context, listen: false).jumlahList
      }
    });  

    // dio.options.baseUrl = Url.postPengajuan;
      var response =
          await dio.post(Url.postPengajuan, data: formdata);
      print(response.data);
  }
```

and here is the error the i got :
[image: img]

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error or what?

Comment: did you try ```jsonEncode(formdata)```?

Comment: @claudioRedi i dont get error on code, but i got error diomixin and paused on exception when post.

Comment: @xion yes, i've try jsondecode. still cant post and get paused on exception

Comment: show the exact error or exception would be helpful

Comment: jsonencode i mean

Comment: @xion, ok , wait a minute

Comment: @xion i've post the error that i got when post.

Comment: @xion i've post the error that i got when post.

Comment: @RichardKyle show the stack instead, this doesn't reflect the actual error, which in your debug console.

Comment: @xion it not show anything in debug console for the error, and not get red for the code when it got paused on exception